# 'struct std::_List_iterator<Sequence*>' has no member named '_Ptr'. Why?

Tags: c++, unix

```
#include "SequenceDatabase.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

// Parameterized constructor
SequenceDatabase::SequenceDatabase()
{
this->sequenceList = list<Sequence *>();
}

//destructor 
SequenceDatabase::~SequenceDatabase(){}

// method to find an entry in the list

//method to process the line passed and get the commands 
void SequenceDatabase::processLine(string line)
{
char *charPrtLine = new char[line.length() + 1];
strcpy(charPrtLine, line.c_str());
char * command = strtok (charPrtLine," \t");

if(command[0] == 'p' || command[0] == 'P') // Print
{
    char * idStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    long id = atol(idStr);
    cout << "Note: Printing " << id << "...\n";
    bool idFound = false;
    list<Sequence*>::iterator iter = sequenceList.begin();  // iterator to the list 
    while(iter != sequenceList.end())
    {
        if(iter._Ptr->_Myval->getId() == id)
        {
            iter._Ptr->_Myval->print();
            idFound = true;
            break;
        }
        iter++;
    }
    if(!idFound)
        cout << "Can not find item (" << id << ") !\n";
}  
else if(command[0] == 'o' || command[0] == 'O') // obliterate
{
    char * idStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    long id = atol(idStr);
    cout << "Note: Obliterating " << id << "...\n";
    bool idFound = false;
    list<Sequence*>::iterator iter = sequenceList.begin();  // iterator to the list 
    while(iter != sequenceList.end())
    {
        if(iter._Ptr->_Myval->getId() == id)
        {
            sequenceList.remove(iter._Ptr->_Myval);
            idFound = true;
            break;
        }
        iter++;
    }
    if(!idFound)
        cout << "Can not delete item (" << id << "), NOT found!\n";
}

else if(command[0] == 'd' || command[0] == 'D') // DNA
{
    char * labelStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    string label(labelStr);

    char * idStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    long id = atol(idStr);

    char * SeqStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    string seq(SeqStr);

    char * seqLenStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    unsigned int seqLen = atoi(seqLenStr);

    char * indexCodeRegStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    int indexCodeReg = atoi(indexCodeRegStr);

    this->sequenceList.push_back(new DNA(label,id,seq,seqLen,indexCodeReg));
}
else if(command[0] == 'r' || command[0] == 'R') // RNA
{
    char * labelStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    string label(labelStr);

    char * idStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    long id = atol(idStr);

    char * SeqStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    string seq(SeqStr);

    char * seqLenStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    unsigned int seqLen = atoi(seqLenStr);

    char * typeRNAStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    int typeRNA = atoi(typeRNAStr);

    this->sequenceList.push_back(new RNA(label,id,seq,seqLen,(typeOfRNA)typeRNA));
}
else if(command[0] == 'a' || command[0] == 'A') // AA
{
    char * labelStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    string label(labelStr);

    char * idStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    long id = atol(idStr);

    char * SeqStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    string seq(SeqStr);

    char * seqLenStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    unsigned int seqLen = atoi(seqLenStr);

    char * readingFrameStr = strtok (NULL," \t");
    int readingFrame = atoi(readingFrameStr);

    this->sequenceList.push_back(new AA(label,id,seq,seqLen,readingFrame));
}
else if(command[0] == 's' || command[0] == 'S') // Size of the master list
{
    cout << "Entries: "
        << this->sequenceList.size()    << " total\n";
}
delete [] charPrtLine;
}
//method to import entries from the supplied command file 
void SequenceDatabase::importEntries(string fileName)
{
string line;
const char * ttt = fileName.c_str();
ifstream myfile (ttt);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    while ( getline(myfile,line) )
    {
        this->processLine(line);           
    }
    myfile.close();
}
}
```

The code compiles fine in Visual Studio, but not in Unix terminal using g++.

errors that pop up in g++:

In member function 'void SequenceDatabase::processLine(string line)':

32,34,52,54: error: 'struct std::_List_iterator' has no member named '_Ptr'

I realize using the _Ptr member is why it doesn't work in Unix terminal using g++, but how could I replace it to work in both Visual Studio and Unix?

Comment: `_Ptr` is an implementation detail of Microsoft's implementation of C++. It's not guaranteed to be there by the standard, and is thus not portable at all. If you would consult an intro to iterators, you would see that you dereference them to get the value, just like with pointers.

Comment: There's no need to use the implementation details of the library here. As chris said, you can just dereference the iterator to obtain a reference to the element.